# pending intent / alarm not working second time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

My code is like this, on button click i execute

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()+(1000*5));

                Intent intent = new Intent(LogoFrontScreen.this,Doubletest.class);
                PendingIntent alarmIntent =    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LogoFrontScreen.this,2,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
                PendingIntent alarmIntent1 =    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LogoFrontScreen.this,2,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calendar.getTimeInMillis()+(2000), alarmIntent1);
```

then on receiver there is a log but that log is called only once, why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of

```
alarmMgr.setExact
```

Try

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating
```

And for scheduling multiple alarm you need to use unique id every time creating

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent =    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LogoFrontScreen.this,2,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The second argument of getBroadcast(i.e. 2 in your case) need to be different for every alarm.

Hope it will solve your problem :)

Comment: but i am setting it 2000ms  after, why am i having problem

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it will help :)

Comment: but Pending has flag update current so it will give the same pending intent twice ,which is what i need.

Comment: You are already creating PendingIntent twice(alarmIntent and alarmIntent1). Just you need to create it with different ids, If for alarmIntent  you are using 2 as id, then for alarmIntent1 use 3 as id. Hope this little change will solve your problem :)

Comment: i am simulating a case where same thing happens twice. it should work , why is it not working with same id.

Comment: The system diffenciates different alarm on the base of this id only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114824/discussion-between-neo-and-shreyans-jain).